# jQuery Tablesorter: custom parser on dynamic table

Tags: jquery, parsing, tablesorter

I have a custom parser called `agoSort` on a column with time difference values like "3 hours ago", "1 week ago", etc.

It's added using the `headers` argument:

`$(".data-table").tablesorter({
  headers: {
    1 : {
      sorter: 'agoSort'
    }
  }
});`

http://jsfiddle.net/chrisdillon/PGe6q/

All other columns use default sorting. The column order will change based on user selection (before document ready) so I need to be able to assign the custom parser after the table is rendered.

I tried `<th class="{'sorter':'agoSort'}"` without args `$(".data-table").tablesorter();` but no joy. http://jsfiddle.net/chrisdillon/LMHRA/

I know I can find the column with `var agoColumn = $('.some-class').index();`.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Here's a fiddle with Mottie's answer and some sugar: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisdillon/Ja3X4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the column order changes, you can instead set the sorter using a class name ([ref](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-class-name.html)):

```
<th class="sorter-agoSort">Post Date</th>
```

If the column order changes after the table has initialized, use the [`updateAll` method](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#updateall) to update the table cache.

As an aside, if you want to use a library for a more rich natural language date sort, try out something like [sugar](http://sugarjs.com/dates#comparing_dates). Check out [this demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-dates.html)

Comment: Thanks Mottie. I thought I searched the documentation enough but apparently not! The metadata failed because I forgot to include the metadata plugin. And thanks for point out sugar, it looks sweet :D